# Embed picture in outlook mail body excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am trying to embed a range from a worksheet as an image in outlook mail body. It's saving the picture correctly but I only see blank image in the outlook mail body. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Sub View_Email()

    tName = Trim(MAIN.Range("tEmail"))

    If Not tName Like "*@*.*" Then MsgBox "Invalid Email address": Exit Sub

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    'File path/name of the gif file
    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Claims.jpg"

    Set oCht = Charts.Add

    STAT.Range("A3:G26").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
    With oCht
        .Paste
        .Export Filename:=Fname, Filtername:="JPG"
        '.Delete
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = tName
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = STAT.Range("C1").Value
        .HTMLBody = "<html><p>Summary of Claim Status.</p>" & _
                    "<img src=" & Fname & "' height=520 width=750>"
        .display
        '.Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Delete the gif file
    'Kill Fname

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Debug the code and check what is the value of `Fname` and manually check the existence of the file. Open the file and check if the chart exported

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes I did check the fname and picture they both seem fine but the outlook body displays the picture as blank

Comment: Oh I know why... one moment posting an answer

Comment: After seeing the broken image / not showing in the draft email, I clicked send and the image shows correctly  when it arrived.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to add the image and hide it. The position `0` will add and hide it.

```
.Attachments.Add Fname, 1, 0
```

The `1` is the Outlook Constant `olByValue`

Once you add the image then you have to use `"cid:FILENAME.jpg"` as shown below.

Try this

```
With OutMail
    .To = tName
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = STAT.Range("C1").Value
    .Attachments.Add Fname, 1, 0
    .HTMLBody = "<html><p>Summary of Claim Status.</p>" & _
                "<img src=""cid:Claims.jpg""height=520 width=750>"
    .Display
End With
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Adding this incase anyone was having the same trouble I was, remember in HTML you can't have spaces in your file name :) my pictures were not showing up until I changed my "File Name" to "File_Name".

Comment: @hammythepig Actually, you can but you just need to [encode](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp) your URL to handle spaces in filenames or paths. So to make `File Name` valid, it should be encoded as `File%20Name`.

Comment: For the life of me I can't get this to work - the quotes in the middle ("<img src=""cid:Claims.jpg""height) are really throwing me off (along with potentially trying to attach a .gif instead of a .jpg)

Comment: @Selkie: What problem are you facing?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: I get an "image can't be displayed, link might be broken" - I'm trying to dynamically bring in the filename (Temp_Picture_1.JPG), but I've also tried just the string - I just can't seem to hit on the right "" needed, and copy-pasting the sample results in the compiler complaining about " - tried a chr(34) replacement, but still no go. I'm actually re-writing all of the code at home to make a post now....

Comment: @SiddharthRout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617458/how-to-embed-an-image-into-an-outlook-email-using-vba

Comment: This is a good solution. In addition to that, what needs to be done if the received mail is expected to appear without attachement.. i.e. I want to send mail with embeded image but should not appear as a mail with attachment for its recipient.

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar: In that case you have to sort of embed the image in the email html by first storing the image on a public server and then inserting that link in the html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` MAPI property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"`) using `Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` and refer that attachment through the `src` attribute that matches the value of `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` set on the attachment. `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` corresponds to the `Content-ID` MIME header when the message is sent.

```
attachment = MailItem.Attachments.Add("c:\temp\MyPicture.jpg")
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyId1")
MailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>Test image <img src=""cid:MyId1""></body></html>"
```

Keep in mind that setting content-id is preferable to using the attachment file name in the `<img>` element since it would need to be properly encoded and (if I remember correctly) some e-mail clients have a problem with just using the attachment file name for images.