# How to size and wrap a photo of a range in an email?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a daily task to copy a range of cells into an email.

I managed to do this, with the range being formatted as a photo. (I learnt that copying a range in table format isn't as straight forward as it seems).

How do I code the size and format of the photo produced, height: 9cm, width: 28cm, format as square?

I think I need to do this via the Word editor. I tried `.style.width` but it throws an error.

```vb
Sub email()

    Dim ol As Object 'Outlook.Application
    Dim olEmail As Object 'Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olInsp As Object 'Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wd As Object 'Word.Document

    Sheets("Daily message").Range("B3:L21").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    Set ol = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") '/* if outlook is running, create otherwise */
    Set olEmail = ol.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem

    With olEmail
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        If olInsp.EditorType = 4 Then 'olEditorWord
            Set wd = olInsp.WordEditor
            wd.Range.PasteAndFormat 13 'wdChartPicture
        End If
        .To = "my email"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Daily message"
        .Display
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you seen [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909276/rangetohtml-image-in-cell)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RangeToHTML & Image in Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909276/rangetohtml-image-in-cell)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HTMLBody` property to format the pasted image and the message body in general.

There are three main ways for setting the body of Outlook items:

1. The `Body` property (a plain text).
2. The `HTMLBody` property - allows customizing the body using the HTML markup as shown above.
3. The Word object model. Outlook uses Word as an email editor by default. The `WordEditor` property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class which represents the body.

You can read more about these ways in [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012.aspx).

---

In HTML you can use the `style` attribute to specify the width and height of an image.

```
<img src="img1.jpg" style="width:500px;height:600px;">
```

Alternatively, you can use the `width` and `height` attributes:

```
<img src="img2.jpg" width="500" height="600">
```

The `width` and `height` attributes always define the width and height of the image in pixels.

Comment: Hi Eugene - thanks so much for your answer. I'm aware of the word model, however not being particularly well versed in VBA code I found myself at a bit of a loss. Using .HTMLBody, how would I define the desired size?

Comment: You can use `width` and `height` attributes in HTML.

Comment: Apologies - I'm not sure how to put this into the code as the sample code using img src doesn't apply to what I've done - I'm guessing the formatting will need to be within the word editor bit however I am unsure what word editor expression I would need to use to tell it to format width & height.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this to work!

```
Sub RangeToOutlook_Single()

Dim oLookApp As Object
Dim oLookItm As Object
Dim oLookIns As Object

Dim oWrdDoc As Object
Dim oWrdRng As Object

Dim ExcRng As Range

On Error Resume Next

Set oLookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")


    If Err.Number = 429 Then

        Err.Clear
    
        Set oLookApp = Object
        
    End If
    
Set oLookItm = oLookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)


Set ExcRng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4:L26")

With oLookItm

    //Email
    .To = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("X1")
    .CC = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V1")
    .Subject = "Here are all of my Ranges"
    .Body = "Here are all the Ranges from my worksheet."
    
    'Display the email
    .Display
    
    'Get the Active Inspector
    Set oLookIns = .GetInspector
    
    'Get the document within the inspector
    Set oWrdDoc = oLookIns.WordEditor

    
    ExcRng.Copy
    
    Set oWrdRng = oWrdDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Content
        oWrdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        
    Set oWrdRng = oWdEditor.Paragraphs.Add
        oWrdRng.InsertBreak
                
    oWrdRng.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture


End With
```