# How to embed an image into an Outlook email using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Very closely related to [Embed picture in outlook mail body excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869790/embed-picture-in-outlook-mail-body-excel-vba/44870371?noredirect=1#comment103543944_44870371)

I'm trying to embed an image into an Outlook email.

I'm using the following code snippet, half of which has been stolen from the post above:

```
Sub PictureEmail()
    Dim outApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Attchmnt As String
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
   Attchmnt = "C:\Users\Blah\Painted_Lady_Migration.jpg"


    Set OutMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
    .To = WB.Names("to").RefersToRange.Value2
    .CC = WB.Names("cc").RefersToRange.Value2
    .BCC = WB.Names("bcc").RefersToRange.Value2
    .Subject = WB.Names("Subject").RefersToRange.Value2
   .HTMLBody = "<img src=""cid:Painted_Lady_Migration.jpg""height=520 width=750>"
   .display
   End With

   If Attchmnt = "" Then
   Else
   OutMail.Attachments.Add Attchmnt
   End If

   On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

However, when looking at the generated email, I have the error "The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted".

I've tried a few different ways to attach the file, including:

```
.HTMLBody = "<img src=" & Chr(34) & "cid:Painted_Lady_Migration.jpg" & Chr(34) & "height=520 width=750>"
```

I just can't get it to work >_<

I saw somewhere that spaces in the name/filepath can throw it, so I replaced the spaces in the name with underscores

What dumb thing am I forgetting/missing?

Comment: Dont you want to add the attachment before executing `.Display`?

Comment: .......... welp. Want to make that an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You missed the part... `.Attachments.Add Attchmnt, 1, 0` from the other post :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: That's what I get for trying to recreate code at home XD. The original at work has it

Comment: The code from the linked post worked just fine for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cid` is created when you attach it, so you need to do that before you display/send it.

Try it like this

```
Set OutMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .To = WB.Names("to").RefersToRange.Value2
    .CC = WB.Names("cc").RefersToRange.Value2
    .BCC = WB.Names("bcc").RefersToRange.Value2
    .Subject = WB.Names("Subject").RefersToRange.Value2
    If Attchmnt <> "" Then 
       .Attachments.Add Attchmnt ' (additional arguments are optional)
       .HTMLBody = "<img src=""cid:Painted_Lady_Migration.jpg"" height=520 width=750>"
    Else
       .HTMLBody = "[no attachment included]"
    End If
   .Display
End With
```

Comment: This works great in a single email! I can successfully generate the picture and attach it... just not working in the giant code I have... going to have a fun debugging session trying to figure out why >_<. Going to start small, and keep adding pieces until it breaks or until it works