# How to add JPG file at specific location in email body created from a template?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to distribute emails using an Outlook oft template.
On the oft template, at a specific location, I want to attach a jpg file which I have created from Excel range.

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim str_jpeg_file as String
str_jpeg_file  = "B:\temp\test.jpg"
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Test.oft")
With OutMail
    .To = "test@abcd.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Test mail"
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "zyz@abcd"
    .Attachments.Add str_jpeg_file, 1, 0
    .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "##IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER##", "<img src=""cid:test.jpg""height=520 width=750>")
    '.Send
    .display
End With
```

Edit:

jpg file path updated i.e. `str_jpeg_file`

Comment: What about the [Attachments.Add method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add)? If you do this `"<img src='" & jpg_file_path & "'" & " ><br>"` the `jpg_file_path` will point to your local computer and the one who gets the mail cannot access it because on his computer it does not exist.

Comment: Attachments.Add method will attach the file to email but the requirement here is to Add jpg file into the email body at specific location. Actually,`"<img src='" & jpg_file_path & "'" & " ><br>"` this line here is adding the image into the email body at top on the email body

Comment: But you need to attach the file first before you can embed it in the HTML body because of the reason I mentioned in my first comment! You need to send the image along with your email otherwise the recepient doesn't have it and cannot see it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed picture in outlook mail body excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869790/embed-picture-in-outlook-mail-body-excel-vba)

Comment: [Embed picture in outlook mail body excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869790/embed-picture-in-outlook-mail-body-excel-vba) This will work for complete fresh email but for existing oft template it will not work. it will override the existing email body.

Comment: You will of course need to have eg. a placeholder in your template that you can replace with your `<img>` tag then. So read the `.HTMLBody` replace your placeholder and write it back to `.HTMLBody`. Syntax similar to: `.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, strFind, strNew)`. But note that your `src=` must look like `<img src=""cid:filename.jpg""height=520 width=750>"` starting with `cid:` and  only the filename not the complete path as in the link.

Comment: how do we have placeholder in oft template ?

Comment: Just write a **unique** text into your template that you can then replace: Eg write in your templete `##IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER##` and then replace that later with your `<img src="cid:filename.jpg" height=520 width=750>` in your VBA code.

Comment: Thank you, i'm getting close now. The object is inserted where i want but it is giving an error saying _The Linked image cannot be displayed, the file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted. verify that the link points to the correct file and location_

Comment: I have added this line to attached the file `.Attachments.Add str_jpeg_file, 1, 0`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show how your code looks like now.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, i have updated the line on the edit

Comment: What is the value of `str_jpeg_file` ?

Comment: `.Attachments.Add str_jpeg_file, 1, 0` This method has a drawback. If you are sending this email to non outlook clients (for example gmail) then this will not look nice. All the images will pile up at the bottom. You will have to upload the image in a free file sharing server(Ex: imgur) and then use the link in the html body. This way the mailer can be viewed in any of the email client.

Comment: `str_jpeg_file` is the path for the file. Also, my all clients are outlook clients.

Comment: `str_jpeg_file is the path for the file.` I understand that. I just didn't see you setting it's value and hence wanted to reconfirm. What problem are you facing with the above code?

Comment: **The Linked image cannot be displayed, the file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted. verify that the link points to the correct file and location** i'm getting this error on the image object with red cross.

Comment: What is the exact value of `str_jpeg_file`? Tell us the result of `Debug.Print str_jpeg_file`. In this code above this variable is never set, so it is empty. Please make sure you include all the necessary information and code.

Comment: value updated for `str_jpeg_file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you a full working example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim str_jpeg_file As String
    str_jpeg_file = "C:\Temp\test.png"
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Test.oft")
    'instead of a template I create a new mail
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .To = "test@abcd.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Test mail"
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "zyz@abcd"
        .Attachments.Add str_jpeg_file, 1, 0
        'first we write some placeholder text so we can replace it
        .HTMLBody = "lalala ##IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER## lala"

        'replace
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "##IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER##", "<img src=""cid:test.png""height=256 width=256>")
        '.Send
        .display
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that I used a new email (no template) because it is easier to show here.

And it works perfectly:

[image]

So if it doesn't work for you either your image file is no valid image or you did something else wrong like typos etc. or your template is somehow the issue. Check again with the code above.

Comment: `str_jpeg_file = "C:\Temp\test.png"`, could you please try jpg file

Comment: Thank you @Peh. It is working for `.png` file format. tested for oft template and new mail

Comment: @1S1a4m9 well it must work for `.jpg` exactly the same there is no difference. I bet there was either a typo or a broken jpeg.

Comment: Ok, i will check.