# Pictures pasted on the body of outlook email are not displayed

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I used the code below to copy a range from a file and paste it as a picture on emails, but there's a catch: if you don´t use .display before .send, the picture will not be displayed to the receiver.
Does anyone know a way around this? Just to avoid the outlook window flashing on the screen.

```
Sub sendMail()

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim NewMail As Object
    Dim ChartName As String
    Dim imgPath As String

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    tmpImageName = VBA.Environ$("temp") & "\tempo.jpg"

    Workbooks.Open "C:\FilePath\File.xlsm"
    Set RangeToSend = Workbooks("File.xlsm").Sheets(Name).Range(" ")

    RangeToSend.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    Set sht = Sheets.Add
    sht.Shapes.AddChart
    sht.Shapes.Item(1).Select
    Set objChart = ActiveChart

    With objChart
        .ChartArea.Height = RangeToSend.Height
        .ChartArea.Width = RangeToSend.Width
        .ChartArea.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
        .Paste
        .Export Filename:=tmpImageName, FilterName:="JPG"
    End With

    sht.Delete

    Workbooks("File.xlsm").Close

    Set NewMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

    With NewMail
        .Subject = "Latest performance report" ' Replace this with your Subject
        .To = "email@email.com" ' Replace it with your actual email
        .HTMLBody = "<span LANG=EN>" _
            & "<p class=style2><span LANG=EN><font FACE=Calibri SIZE=3>" _
            & "Hello, this is the data range that you want:<br> " _
            & "<br>" _
            & "<img src=" & "'" & tmpImageName & "'/>" _
            & "<br>" _
            & "<img src=" & "'" & tmpImageName2 & "'/>" _
            & "<br>" _
            & "<br>Best Regards!</font></span>"
        .Display
        .Send

        Set olApp = Nothing
        Set NewMail = Nothing
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the body format `.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML`?

Comment: Have you seen [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869790/embed-picture-in-outlook-mail-body-excel-vba/44870371#44870371)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are saving the picture captured in Excel to a disk. And then you are referring to the image in a newly created item body. But the image source still points to the file on your disk. So, the recipient will never get it shown correctly.

Instead, you need to attach a file and then add a reference in the message body.

```
Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"        
Const PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B" 

...

Set colAttach = mail.Attachments        
Set l_Attach = colAttach.Add(path_to_the_file)            
Set oPA = l_Attach.PropertyAccessor            

oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "itemID"            
oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN, True
```

Then you can modify the message body in the following way:

```
.HTMLBody = "<span LANG=EN>" _
        & "<p class=style2><span LANG=EN><font FACE=Calibri SIZE=3>" _
        & "Hello, this is the data range that you want:<br> " _
        & "<br>" _
        & "<img src='cid:itemID'/>" _
        & "<br>" _
        & "<br>Best Regards!</font></span>"

    .Send
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is a good alternative, although I still dont understand why I can send the pictures on the body of the email (without attaching the files) if I display the outlook window (with .display command) before sending.