# Display email with text box image and html text

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to automatize creating emails that contains my excel files content. However, the email should contain a table and grittings which I was able to do. But when it comes to the text box that contains the comments, VBA is not able to display it in the email, since it is not in HTML. Because in this code, it deletes the table and grittings, then creates a new email with only the text box as an image. Now I need help so that it is able to create it as a picture and insert it along with the rest, with all the content in the same email. Because my main object is to have an email with grittings, the Excel table, and the text box respecting its font.

Here is the code I tried:

```vb
Sub SendEmail()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim recipient As String
    Dim ccList As String
    Dim subject As String
    Dim body As String
    Dim parite As String
    Dim comment As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rngComment As Range
    Dim shp As Shape
    
    ' Set worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Get recipient email
    recipient = Trim(ws.Range("I6").Value)
    
    ' Get cc list
    For i = 7 To 12
        If Trim(ws.Cells(i, "I").Value) <> "" Then
            ccList = ccList & Trim(ws.Cells(i, "I").Value) & ";"
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Remove last ";" from ccList
    If Right(ccList, 1) = ";" Then
        ccList = Left(ccList, Len(ccList) - 1)
    End If
    
    ' Get subject
    subject = ws.Range("I4").Value
    
    ' Get parite
    parite = ws.Range("I14").Value
    
    ' Build email body
    body = "<p>Bonjour,</p>" & _
           "<p></p>" & _
           "<p>Suite à votre demande, nous vous prions de trouver ci-après notre proposition de couverture sur la base d’une parité EURUSD " & parite & "</p>"
    
    ' Copy table
    ws.Range("A1:D23").Copy
    
    ' Create Outlook application
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' Create new email
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    ' Add recipient, cc, subject, and body
    With OutMail
        .To = recipient
        .CC = ccList
        .subject = subject
        
        ' Add table and closing remarks to the email body
        .HTMLBody = body & RangetoHTML(ws.Range("A1:D23")) & "<br><br>"
        
        ' Copy text box as image and insert into email body
        .GetInspector.Activate
        ws.Shapes("TextBox 1").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        .GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.Paste
        
        .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br><br>Cordialement,"
        .Display ' Change to .Send to automatically send email
    End With
    
    ' Clean up
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range) As String
    ' Convert range to HTML
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    Dim rngCopy As Range
    Dim rowCounter As Long
    Dim colCounter As Long
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim startCol As Long
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim endCol As Long
    Dim hasData As Boolean

    ' Initialize startRow, startCol, endRow, endCol
    startRow = rng.Rows.Count
    startCol = rng.Columns.Count
    endRow = 1
    endCol = 1

    ' Find the startRow and endRow
    For rowCounter = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        hasData = False
        For colCounter = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Cells(rowCounter, colCounter)) Then
                hasData = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next colCounter
        If hasData Then
            If rowCounter < startRow Then startRow = rowCounter
            If rowCounter > endRow Then endRow = rowCounter
        End If
    Next rowCounter

    ' Find the startCol and endCol
    For colCounter = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        hasData = False
        For rowCounter = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Cells(rowCounter, colCounter)) Then
                hasData = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next rowCounter
        If hasData Then
            If colCounter < startCol Then startCol = colCounter
            If colCounter > endCol Then endCol = colCounter
        End If
    Next colCounter

    ' Create a new range excluding empty cells within the identified block
    Set rngCopy = Nothing
    For rowCounter = startRow To endRow
        For colCounter = startCol To endCol
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Cells(rowCounter, colCounter)) Then
                If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngCopy = rng.Cells(rowCounter, colCounter)
                Else
                    Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, rng.Cells(rowCounter, colCounter))
                End If
            End If
        Next colCounter
    Next rowCounter

    ' Check if there's no data in the range
    If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
        RangetoHTML = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Convert rngCopy to HTML
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    rngCopy.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    ' Publish the sheet to an htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    ' Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    ' Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

    ' Delete the htm file
    Kill TempFile

    ' Clean up
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: See if [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869790/embed-picture-in-outlook-mail-body-excel-vba) helps you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find all the information you need at this address:

[Automating Email Content Creation with Excel and VBA](https://www.tempmail.us.com/en/excel/automating-email-content-creation-with-excel-and-vba)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).