Embed Excel Range as Image in Outlook Mail
I previously used the Ron De Bruin RangetoHTML function to embed an Excel range as an image in Outlook mail. New Trust Centre settings prohibit this and I cannot change them.
I switched to MailEnvelope, but again some security setting prevents this. .Display works some of the time but not consistently.
I am now looking at a solution that attaches the range as a picture to the body of the email. I cannot get the image to display in the body.
I can add as an attachment. Changing the 0 to a 1 attaches the physical file.
.Attachments.Add strTempFilePath, olByValue, 0

Running Windows 11 and Office 365.
Sub a()
Call Create_Email("first.last@domain.com", "test2")
End Sub

Sub Create_Email(ByVal strTo As String, ByVal strSubject As String)

    Dim rngToPicture As Range
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim Outmail As Object
    Dim strTempFilePath As String
    Dim strTempFileName As String

    'Name it anything, doesn't matter
    strTempFileName = "RangeAsPNG"

    'rngToPicture is defined as NAMED RANGE in the workbook, do modify this name before use
    Set rngToPicture = Range("A1:D30")
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Outmail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'Create an email
    With Outmail
        .To = strTo
        .Subject = strSubject

        'Create the range as a PNG file and store it in temp folder
        Call createPNG(rngToPicture, strTempFileName)

        'Embed the image in Outlook
        strTempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & strTempFileName & ".png"
        .Attachments.Add strTempFilePath, olByValue, 0
        .HTMLBody = "Hello"
        .Display
    End With

    Set Outmail = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing
    Set rngToPicture = Nothing

End Sub

Sub createPNG(ByRef rngToPicture As Range, nameFile As String)

    Dim wksName As String

    wksName = rngToPicture.Parent.Name

    'Delete the existing PNG file of same name, if exists
    On Error Resume Next
        Kill Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".png"
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Copy the range as picture
    rngToPicture.CopyPicture

    'Paste the picture in Chart area of same dimensions
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wksName).ChartObjects.Add(rngToPicture.Left, rngToPicture.Top, rngToPicture.Width, rngToPicture.Height)
        .Activate
        .Chart.Paste
        'Export the chart as PNG File to Temp folder
        .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".png", "PNG"
    End With
    
    Worksheets(wksName).ChartObjects(Worksheets(wksName).ChartObjects.Count).Delete

End Sub


There are several SO answers for this, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869790/embed-picture-in-outlook-mail-body-excel-vba

Your HTML body does not even refer to the image - you need an <img> tag and it needs to reference the image added as an attachment through the src=cid: attribute and the content-id property set on the attachment itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72017591/332059
